# Pandas data frame returning 1D multiple arrays to multiple Data Frame rather than single data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an images data set which I have converted into NumPy array and getting total counts of pixels in individual images. I am using below code for this purpose:

```
data_custom_script = images
data_custom_script = np.array(data_custom_script)
import pandas as pd


for images in data_custom_script:
    
    colours, counts = np.unique(images.reshape(-1,3), axis=0, return_counts=1)
   #giving these conditions because array has different shapes
    if counts.shape[0] == 7:
       counts = np.reshape(counts,(1,7))
    if counts.shape[0] == 6:
       counts = np.reshape(counts,(1,6))     
    if counts.shape[0] == 5:
       counts = np.reshape(counts,(1,5))
    if counts.shape[0] == 4:
       counts = np.reshape(counts,(1,4))
    if counts.shape[0] == 3:
       counts = np.reshape(counts,(1,3))
```

Now when I run this code i get result into multiple 1D array for each images like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0kp4.png)

Now when I convert this into data frame I got results in the form of individual data frames rather than one

```
df = pd.DataFrame(counts)
print(df)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvFA3.png)

I want to get results in the form of a single data frame like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELuSr.png)

Comment: Reshape to `(1,7)` makes a 2d array, displayed as `[[1 2 3]]`.  If you really want that you don't need all the `if`, just do  `counts = counts[None,:]` or `counts=counts.reshape(1,-1)`.  Also, you don't show how you collect the `counts` in the iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. And can you please guide me how can i convert into single data frame rather than multiple data frames for each images

Comment: counts = np.unique(images.reshape(-1,3), axis=0, return_counts=1). This part of code is collecting counts for images